# How to display json array coming from url through ajax in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

I have a json array coming from a url: 
http://blahblahblah.com/company/all, like this:[image: json array]

in angularjs controller, i have something like this:

```
    $('#example-1').DataTable({
        "ajax" : 'http://blahblahblah.com/company/all',
        "columns": [
           {"data": "companyId"},
           {.....}, // I can't assign "data" name to array because it is already unnamed.
        ]
    });
```

Traversing in html table_id example-1

```
<table id="example-1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Legal Name</th>
            <th>DBA Name</th>
            <th>Formation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Legal Name</th>
            <th>DBA Name</th>
            <th>Formation</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Output:

[image]

> So, my question is how do I identify the column names from above UNNAMED JSON ARRAY mentioned on top of the question, and display it in html table. Waiting for your kind response.

I am thinking to do something like this

[image]

Comment: Refer this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: What is the question here

Comment: @JinsPeter the question is how do I display the json array data in html table, like in my case is only showing "loading"

Comment: Will answer after a bit of time. Going for lunch now..btw plz dont use jQuery in angular js controller. use angular service

Comment: @JinsPeter I'm waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to identify the correct syntax of identifying and using the column names in my JSON array, which I did like this, and solved my problem. So now the data is displayed fine in my table, this way:

```
$.getJSON('http://blahblahblah/company/all', function(data) {

            $('#companies').DataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mDataProp":"companyId"},
                    {"mDataProp":"legalName"},
                    {"mDataProp":"dbaName"},
                    {"mDataProp":"formation"}
                ]
            });



        });
```

I also added hyperlink to companyId like this:

```
    $.getJSON('http://blahblahblah/company/all', function(data) {

            var companyId = null;
            $('#companies').DataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mDataProp":"companyId", "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if( type==='display' ) {
                            companyId = data;
                            data = '<a href="' + "/pages/company?companyId=" +companyId+ '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                        return data;
                    }},
                    {"mDataProp":"legalName"},
                    {"mDataProp":"dbaName"},
                    {"mDataProp":"formation"}
                ]
            });



        });
```

I am thankful to all of you for helping me grab the track. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "http://blahblahblah.com/company/all",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "companyId" },
            { "data": "legalName" },
            { "data": "dbaName" },
            { "data": "formation"}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

you need to add more information to the datatable while intializing what are the keys to be shown. form more details check [datatable objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: @BadshahTracker did you check the documentation?

Comment: why are we providing "data" attribute for column name?

Comment: @BadshahTracker that is array name.not plain data.{data:[...]} so we put data there

Comment: @BadshahTracker your response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162396/discussion-between-badshah-tracker-and-zabusa).

Comment: please see the answer I provided to my question, I solved it that way. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Actual way to do this is to use ng-repeat in the data array. And for the data fetch, use an angular service with a promise.

**In the Controller**

```
var self = this;// this is the controller which is aliased as ctrl at routing

var theData = yourService.FetchData(params).then(function(data){
      self.tableData = data; // not going for the exact implementation.

},function(err){
      manageError(err);// manage your errors here.
}));
```

**In the HTML**

```
<table id="example-1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Legal Name</th>
        <th>DBA Name</th>
        <th>Formation</th>
    </tr>
</thead>


 <tr ng-repeat="var item in ctrl.tableData ">
       <td>{{item.companyId}}</td>
       <td>{{item.legalName}}</td>
       <td>{{item.dbaName}}</td>
       <td>{{item.formation}}</td>
 </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I tried it, it is working. But then I lost the functionalities for pagination and search-sort.

Comment: ok then just tell me how do I add pagination, searching and sorting in this html table you have provided in the answer.

Comment: I can mark your question as accepted if you could please add pagination, searching and sorting on your html table.

Comment: You using angularJS for the first time?/

Comment: yes it is the first time I am working over a theme in angularjs.

Comment: Theme? u mean ui. why do u use jQuery datatable. google how to use ng-table

Comment: yes ui. and not I am using but it is already provided in the theme and I'm just re-using the code.

Comment: there in the code,it is something like this:
"ajax": 'assets/json/datatable.json'

in which I am removing the json file and providing the url

Comment: ur data json is in that file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162414/discussion-between-jins-peter-and-badshah-tracker).